# Microsoft.Contracts namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-contracts, design-by-contract, microsoft-contracts

For what it is necessary Microsoft.Contracts namespace in asp.net?

I mean, in what cases I could write `using Microsoft.Contracts;`?

Comment: The question is unclear, I'm afraid. Can you re-word it?

Comment: OP is asking "What is the Microsoft.Conracts" namespace for, and when would you use it.

Answer (score 3):

For using [code contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx).

Comment: I might sound like a douche.. But I think you should phrase it like "For using code contracts" or "I think it's for using code contracts". I think the ? just makes it looks snobby in this case, and I don't think thats your intention.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't think a simple question mark could make such a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the library here
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll