# What is Microsoft.Contracts and where is it coming from?

Tags: .net

I have a custom SharePoint job that is erroring out when it tries to run.  When I look at the error i see:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=736440c9b414ea16' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

I've searched my solution and there is no reference to this anywhere.  Where could this be coming from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft.Contracts namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679392/microsoft-contracts-namespace)

Comment: @Justin, my question also asks about how it could be part of an error when it's not part of my solution.  Your possible duplicate does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft.Contracts ([CodeContracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx)) is the assembly in which are contained the methods that "provides a language-agnostic way to express coding assumptions in .NET programs".

Maybe some external assembly is searching this one.

Comment: How would I track down which external assembly has the reference?

Comment: I think Redgate .NET Reflector could help you :)

Comment: I'm already using that.  I've gone through all the .NET assemblies and there is nothing.

Comment: Maybe with some other software you have installed CodeContracts and now there is a broken reference. If you create a new project and run it, does it work ?

Comment: I ended up using NDepend to find who was using it.

Comment: If you think the answer could help other people, please post it :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or earlier, you need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Contracts.dll` that is installed under:
`%PROGRAMFILES%/Microsoft/Contracts/PublicAssemblies`

Answer (score 2):

`Microsoft.Contracts` is the main assembly of the [Microsoft Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx) system. If its not used by your actual code, it could well be used by a referenced library.

In theory you should be able to remove all code related to it and your program should run the same. It is after all just a way of enforcing practices and helping with testing. In practice, I'm not so sure...

> Code Contracts provide a
>   language-agnostic way to express
>   coding assumptions in .NET programs.
>   The contracts take the form of
>   pre-conditions, post-conditions, and
>   object invariants. Contracts act as
>   checked documentation of your external
>   and internal APIs. The contracts are
>   used to improve testing via runtime
>   checking, enable static contract
>   verification, and documentation
>   generation. Code Contracts bring the
>   advantages of design-by-contract
>   programming to all .NET programming
>   languages. We currently provide three
>   tools:

The full version is only available in VS 2010 Premium/Ultimate, but apparently you can get a "standard edition" for other versions of VS.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the library here
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll